AES encrypt in Angular and decrypt in Python
I am trying to encrypt a password in Angular using crypto-js and decrypt in Python using pycryptodome.
My Angular code is -
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
secretKey = "lazydog";
password = "This is to be encrypted";
enc: any;
encrypt(value : string) : string{
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, this.secretKey.trim()).toString();
  }
decrypt(textToDecrypt : string){
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(textToDecrypt, this.secretKey.trim()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }

In the constructor -
this.enc = this.encrypt(this.password);
console.log(this.enc);

In Python, my code is -
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import base64
secretKey = "lazydog"
data = "s2SS6ugKbTGjTaT0U+X8mw=="
def encrypt(raw):
        raw = pad(raw.encode(),16)
        cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_ECB)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))
def decrypt(enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_ECB)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc),16)

decrypted = decrypt(encrypted)
print('data: ',decrypted.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))

I am getting error that the padding is incorrect.
Please someone help as I am not good in it. PS: I tried most of the available solutions in stack overflow and internet to no avail.

CryptoJS uses the key derivation function (KDF) EVP_BytesToKey() when the key material is passed as string, which generates a 32 bytes key and 16 bytes IV under the hood. Also, CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(...).toString() returns the Base64 encoding of the concatenation of the ASCII encoding of Salted__ plus 8 bytes salt plus ciphertext. All this is missing in the Python code! Alternatively, key and IV can be passed as WordArray in the CryptoJS code, then they are applied directly (i.e. without KDF).

Incidentally, the Python code is not executable. Neither key nor encrypted are defined and if secretKey and data are used instead, an Incorrect AES key length error message is thrown because the key length is too short for AES (AES keys are 16, 24 or 32 bytes in size). In addition, the ciphertext cannot have been generated with the CryptoJS code, as its ciphertexts always begin with U2FsdGVkX1 (when using the KDF). Please check the code and post consistent data.

According to the docs, the default mode in crypto-js is CBC, and you're using ECB on the Python side. Try AES.MODE_CBC instead.
